# Changing innerHTML to value from div's Id captured by it's ClassName

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have some buttons 1-9 and i want to show their numbers on div called "screen". So i wrote such code, but it not seem to work.

Piece of HTML code with those buttons:

```
  <div id="screen"></div>

  <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key7" value="7" onclick="enterPIN();"></div>
  <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key8" value="8" onclick="enterPIN();"></div>
  <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key9" value="9" onclick="enterPIN();"></div>
       <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key4" value="4" onclick="enterPIN();"></div>
   <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key5" value="5" onclick="enterPIN();"></div>
       (... AND SO ON ...)
```

JavaScript code:

```
function enterPIN()
{
    for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("numKey").length; i++)
    {
        var numKeyId = i + " " + document.getElementsByClassName("numKey")[i].id;
        console.log(numKeyId);
        return numKeyId;

    }

    var getElementId = function(numKeyId)
    {
        this.numKeyId = numKeyId;
        document.getElementById("screen").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("numKey")[numKeyId].id;
        console.log("Asdasdasd");
    }
    getElementId();
}
```

**It should work like this:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just passing the value you want to display directly, as in `onclick="enterPIN(4);`?

Comment: Is it just me or did you get the numKeyId wrong? It could be just me, it's pretty late and I'm just done with my work. EDIT: Yeah, I think it's just me, sorry. EDIT2: If you don't want to put `enterPIN(4);` like Daniel suggested, why not rely on `this` more? just get a value and put in `element.innerHTML += "4"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/nmaqsudov/ur9mhwzg/)

```
window.onload = function(){
    var MAX_LEN = 4,
        currentValue = "",
        elScreen = document.getElementById('screen'),
        addDigit = function(digit){
            digit = digit instanceof MouseEvent ? this.value : digit;
            if (elScreen.innerHTML.length < MAX_LEN) elScreen.innerHTML += digit;
        },
        delDigit = function(){
            elScreen.innerHTML = elScreen.innerHTML.slice(0,elScreen.innerHTML.length - 1);
        };
    //setting handlers for numKeys
    numBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('numKey');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < numBtns.length; i++) numBtns[i].onclick = addDigit;
    //setting handler for backKey
    document.getElementById('backKey').onclick = delDigit;
}
```

Do not think about event handlers first. Write simple functions `addDigit` and `delDigit`, and after call them from handlers.

Comment: Thanks for extra delete function.

Answer (score 4):

The first time the for loop iterates (with `i=0`), it will get to the `return` statement and the function will quit after just one iteration never reaching the last part of the script.

This can be done with less code if you just change the HTML a little bit by putting the value as an argument to `enterPin`:

```
<input type="button" class="numKey" id="key7" value="7" onclick="enterPIN(7);">
```

Or, as suggested by bcdan, by using `this` so you don't have to repeat yourself:

```
<input type="button" class="numKey" id="key7" value="7" onclick="enterPIN(this.value);">
```

Do note that I changed from `submit` to `button` since you do not actually want to submit the form once the buttons are pressed. Then you just need this JS:

```
function enterPin(number) {
    screen = document.getElementById("screen");
    screen.innerHTML = screen.innerHTML + String(number);
}
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery (and get rid of the `onclick` attribute):

```
$(".numKey").click(function() {
    screen = $("#screen");
    screen.html(screen.html + this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you just need it to output what you click, why not do something like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        function enterPIN(value)
        {
            document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += String(value);
        }

        </script>

        <div id="screen"></div>

        <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key7" value="7" onclick="enterPIN(this.value);"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key8" value="8" onclick="enterPIN(this.value);"></div>
        <div><input type="submit" class="numKey" id="key9" value="9" onclick="enterPIN(this.value);"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to pass `this.value` in the `onclick` function parameters (as @DanielBeck suggests):

```
<input type="button" value="1" onclick="enterPIN(this.value)"/>
```

This is much simpler than trying to pull out which button was pressed, when that information can be directly delivered.

Comment: Yes it works - thanks @Daniel Black - but since i wrote such function to output all those button value numbers. How to do it by for-loop and so on as my code is trying to do :)? How to wrote my code correctly to make it work?